# Why Facebook profile picture of website page looks bad?

Tags: facebook

I have tried to upload .png and .jpg but profile picture looks bad. Maybe because of Facebook optimization of image. 
NOTE: it also happens when I save this image in photo album.

Bad:
[image]

Good: 
[image]

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried cropping it with a photo editor just the part you want like say on a windows machine use paint. Cut it and then paste the image in a new file and save it as a png, or jpg or whatever. And then from there try uploading it into facebook. Should be fine from there.

Comment: Yeah, try making it the right size from the beginning, and also try to keep file size small … I had better results with uploaded page profile picture etc. if Facebook didn’t have to resize them themselves. (Although the will most likely still “optimize” them, but having them in the right size usually prevents the result from being real ugly.)

Comment: Yeah there is no real solution to that, facebook is kinda odd with that. and dont get me started with forcing timeline on me lol.